# How to use echarts-gl with echarts

Tags: echarts

I am learning to use echarts.js for my project.

I would like to know to use the extension echarts-gl (for 3D graphics) with ES modules. The documentation is very succinct and I am just a noobie.

In fact, I am trying to use echarts-gl together with the echarts-for-vue, anyone have tried it?

My main.js looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import { plugin } from 'echarts-for-vue';
import * as echarts from 'echarts/esm/echarts';
import 'echarts/esm/chart/line';
import 'echarts/esm/chart/bar';
import 'echarts/esm/component/title';
import 'echarts/esm/component/tooltip';
import 'echarts/esm/component/legend';
import 'echarts/esm/component/toolbox';
import 'echarts/esm/component/polar';
import 'echarts/esm/component/visualMap';
// require('echarts-gl/lib/echarts-gl');
// import '../assets/echarts-gl.js';
// import 'echarts-gl/lib/component/grid3D';
// import 'echarts-gl/lib/chart/surface';
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(plugin, { echarts });
new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

I don't know where or how to include the imports for echarts-gl. Do I need webpack configuration?
Sorry about my lack of expertise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked when I just imported it like this:

```
import 'echarts';
import 'echarts-gl';
```

Also make sure to use a compatible version of echarts-gl with echarts.

```
(
    "echarts": "4.9.0",
    "echarts-gl": "1.1.2",
    "vue-echarts": "4.1.0",
)
```